# getRotation() of layout in Android 2.1

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android application I have build for Platform 4.0.3 and I have used getRotation() and setRotation() Methods to rotate my layout

but I have to make the same application for Platform 2.1 and when I try to do that I can't find getRotation() or setRotation() Methods

so if anyone know the corresponding methods or way to do so I will be Thankful

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use rotation animation to rotate it based on to and from values in a specific time

Answer (score 0):

You could set android:orientation="vertical" in the manifest to force the layout to get set a certain way.